# I don't know how to output files and create additional programs

Tags: c

I wanted to make the following program, so I made it halfway, but I don't know how to make it from there. I will give you the result you want to execute and the result of the current execution. Where should I edit?
want to execute.

```
Please enter three values:
5.0 9.0 -6.5
Average: 2.500
Original data: +5.000 +9.000 -6.500
Data after average deduction: +2.500 +6.500 -9.000
```

now to execute.

```
Please enter three values: 
5.0 9.0 -6.5
Average:2.500 
Original data:5.000 9.000 -6.500 
Data after average deduction:2.500 6.500 -9.000
```

source

```
#include <stdio.h>

double ave3 (double, double, double);
double subave3 (double *, double *, double *);

int main ()
{
   double a, b, c, ave;

   printf ("Please enter three values: \n");
   scanf ("%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c);

   ave = ave3 (a, b, c); /* Function call */

   printf ("Average:%.3f \n", ave);
   printf ("Original data:%.3f %.3f %.3f \n", a, b, c);

   subave3 (&a, &b, &c);

   printf ("Data after average deduction:%.3f %.3f %.3f \n", a, b, c);

   return 0;
}

/* A function that calculates the average. It also subtracts the average value from the data. */
double subave3 (double *x, double *y, double *z)
{
    double ave = ave3(*x,*y,*z);
   *x-= ave; /* Subtract the average from each data */
   *y-= ave;
   *z-= ave;
}

double ave3 (double x, double y, double z) {
   double ave = (x +  y + z) / 3.0;
   return ave;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ? What to you want to execute ? Why does your post title mention output files ?

Comment: Which additional programs are you talking about? What is your problem? Are you talking about adding the `+` in the output?

Comment: yes. I wanna add +.

Comment: Please [edit] your question (the title) do reflect the real question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `+` like this:

```c
printf ("Original data:%+.3f %+.3f %+.3f \n", a, b, c);
...
printf ("Data after average deduction:%+.3f %+.3f %+.3f \n", a, b, c);
```

When you'd run this, you would get this output:

```
src : $ ./a.out 
Please enter three values: 
5.0 9.0 -6.5
Average:2.500 
Original data:+5.000 +9.000 -6.500 
Data after average deduction:+2.500 +6.500 -9.000
```